# Resolve ambiguous operator across namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-keyword

I created my own `<<` overload for `bool` because I wanted it to print `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0`. This usually works, except when I leave the namespace in which I defined this operator. In that case I get an ambiguous operator error.

```
error C2593: 'operator <<' is ambiguous
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ostream(206): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::_Bool)'
with
[
    _Elem=char,
    _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
]
c:\Dummy.h(43): or       'std::ostream &Dummy::operator <<(std::ostream &,bool)'
while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>, bool)'
with
[
    _Elem=char,
    _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
]
```

How do I specify which namespace to take the operator from? Naively I tried `Dummy::<<` and `Dummy::operator<<` but neither worked.

Comment: Are you aware of [std::boolalpha](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) ?

Comment: No I wasn't, that is nice to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at [`std::boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha), but to answer your original question:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Dummy {
  std::ostream&
  operator<< (std::ostream& stream, bool f) {
    return stream << (f ? "7RU3" : "F4LS3");
  }
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cerr      <<   true   <<  "\n";
  Dummy::operator<< (std::cerr, true);
}
```

**output**

```
1
7RU3
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should just use [`std::boolalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/boolalpha/), and save yourself the grief!